# Flask + mysql в контейнер docker

Tags: mysql, docker, flask

Подскажите что не так делаю в docker-compose. Приложение flask не видит базу данных

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask:
    build: .
    container_name: blog-app
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://blog:bx6q!HchQzwa0@127.0.0.1:3306/blog                   
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/blog
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - app:app
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blog
      MYSQL_USER: blog
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: bx6q!HchQzwa0
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sdgfdbefsdgfd
```

Comment: IP-адрес другого контейнера очевидно будет не 127.0.0.1, попробуйте написать хотя бы просто `db` например

Comment: Пробовал и db и dbserver, а как узнать какой хост не подскажите? Отдельно без бд с помощью docker приложение flask  работает, а вот как подружить не знаю, часа 4 убил на поиски

Comment: Хотя если вы прописали `container_name: mysql`, то может так и надо `mysql`

Comment: Тоже пробовал, а так с виду проблема скорее всего а корректности хоста?

Comment: Отдельно оба контейнера собираются и работают, за исключением обращений к бд